# Do you know where to find a library or example of a script to be able to see how much liquidity there is in a contract?

Tags: tokens, web3.py, uniswap, python, pancakeswap

I need to see in a new listed contract in BSC, through python, how much liquidity has been added or possess. I can't find a library and a script as an applied example that can help me see that information.

It takes me a while to see it through Poocoin due to my network connection problems, but with Python the queries are faster.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

My service [Trading Strategy gives you pool liquidity information](https://tradingstrategy.ai/) you are looking for.

You can get both [historical](https://tradingstrategy.ai/trading-view/backtesting) and [real time liquidity added over an API](https://tradingstrategy.ai/api/explorer/). You can also interactively view this on the website.

[image]

[A liquidity chart example for KLIMA-USDC pair](https://tradingstrategy.ai/trading-view/polygon/sushiswap/klima-usdc).

[Read our introduction post on liquidity charts and API](https://tradingstrategy.ai/blog/announcing-support-for-liquidity-charts).

Here is a partial Python example how to get the liquidity at a specific historical timepoint:

```py
import pandas as pd
from tradingstrategy.chain import ChainId
from tradingstrategy.liquidity import GroupedLiquidityUniverse
from tradingstrategy.pair import PandasPairUniverse
from tradingstrategy.timebucket import TimeBucket

#: We use weekly liquidity candles for the calculations
CANDLE_TIMEFRAME = TimeBucket.d7

# Download exchange database
exchange_universe = client.fetch_exchange_universe()

# Download trading pair database
raw_pairs = client.fetch_pair_universe().to_pandas()

# Download liquidity OHLC candles
raw_liquidity_samples = client.fetch_all_liquidity_samples(CANDLE_TIMEFRAME).to_pandas()

# Create a Python helper to manipulate trading pairs
pair_universe = PandasPairUniverse(raw_pairs)

# Create a Python helper to manipulate pair liquidity data
liquidity_universe = GroupedLiquidityUniverse(raw_liquidity_samples)

# Do some test calculations for a single pair
# Note that PancakeSwap has two different deployments:
# you most likely want v2
our_exchange = exchange_universe.get_by_chain_and_slug(ChainId.bsc, "pancakeswap-v2")
assert our_exchange, "Could not find the DEX"

# Query the pair metadata.
# Note that PancakeSwap operates on Wrapped BNB (WBNB), not native BNB token
base_token = "WBNB"
quote_token = "BUSD"
assert our_pair, "Pair not found"

our_pair = pair_universe.get_one_pair_from_pandas_universe(our_exchange.exchange_id, "WBNB", "BUSD")

print(f"Trading pair {base_token}-{quote_token} id is {our_pair.pair_id}, the pool contract address is {our_pair.address}")


# December 2021
when = pd.Timestamp("2021-12-01")

liquidity_samples = liquidity_universe.get_liquidity_samples_by_pair(our_pair.pair_id)
if liquidity_samples is None:
    raise AssertionError(f"The universe does not contain liquidity data for pair {our_pair}")

# Get all liquidity OHLC past the certain timestamp.
# Thus, we query the first available liquidity sample *after* the timestamp.
ranged_samples = liquidity_samples[when:]

if len(ranged_samples) == 0:
    raise AssertionError(f"Pair {our_pair} had no liquidity before {when}")

# Get the first sample in the series
# This presents the liquidity at the first available sampled moment
# since the timestamp.
first_sample = ranged_samples.iloc[0]

# Convert liquidity from USD to token
token_liquidity = first_sample.open * first_sample.exchange_rate

print(f"""
Liquidity sampled at: {first_sample.timestamp}
Liquidity sample period: {CANDLE_TIMEFRAME.value}
Liquidity at the begin: {first_sample.open:,.2f} USD
Liquidity at the end: {first_sample.close:,.2f} USD
Liquidity at the begin, expressed as the quote token: {token_liquidity:.4f} {our_pair.quote_token_symbol}
Liquidity added during the period: {first_sample.add_volume:,.2f} USD
Liquidity removed during the period: {first_sample.remove_volume:,.2f} USD
""")
```

[Read the full source code with the example output here](https://tradingstrategy.ai/docs/programming/examples/pool-liquidity.html).

*Note*: Currently liquidity data is not available to all trading pairs. Only for those that have [a simple route to convert token valuations to US dollar](https://tradingstrategy.ai/docs/programming/referenceprice.html).